# Compute $\langle 3, 5\rangle$ in $U_{16}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

I am asked to compute $\langle 3, 5\rangle$ in $U_{16}$.

$U_{16} = \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 \}$ , i.e., the elements of $\mathbb{Z_{16}}$ that are relatively prime to 16.

In order to calculate $\langle 3, 5\rangle$ in $U_{16}$, do I just find the $\gcd(3,5,16)?$

Comment: Hint: $\langle 3 \rangle=\{3,9,11,1\}$.

Comment: which are $3^1$, $3^2$, $3^3$, and $3^4$ mod 16, but what about when two elements are within the angle brackets?  @vadim123

Comment: How is this read?  The subset generated by 3 and 5?

Comment: Close, the subgroup generated by $3$ and $5$.

Comment: So I found $\langle 5 \rangle = \{ 1, 5, 9, 13 \}.$  Does that mean that I should look for what $\langle 3 \rangle$ and $\langle 5 \rangle$ have in common?  @vadim123

Comment: $\langle 3,5\rangle = \{3^i5^j:i,j\in \mathbb{N}\}$, but only because the group is commutative.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to figure it out @vadim123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\langle 3 \rangle  = \{ 1,3,9,11  \}$ and
$\langle 5 \rangle  = \{ 1,5,9,13  \}$

Make a multiplication table modulo 16.

\begin{matrix}
 1 &  3 &  9 & 11\\
 5 & 15 & 13 &  7\\
 9 & 11 &  1 &  3\\
13 &  7 &  5 & 15\\
\end{matrix}

So $\langle 3,5 \rangle  = \{ 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15  \} = \mathbb U_{16}$

Or you could compute
$|\langle 3,5 \rangle|
 = \dfrac{|\langle 3 \rangle| \cdot |\langle 5 \rangle|}
         {|\langle 3 \rangle| \cap |\langle 5 \rangle|}
 = \dfrac{16}{2} = 8$ and, since $\varphi(16) = 16 - 8 = 8$, then we must have 
$\langle 3,5 \rangle = \mathbb U_{16}$

Comment: So after you compute the multiplication table mod 16, how do you conclude that $\langle 3 , 5 \rangle = \mathbb{U}_{16}$?

Comment: Also, since the cardinality of $\langle 3, 5 \rangle$ is equal to the Euler phi (totient) function of 16, then we can conclude that $\langle 3, 5 \rangle$ has 8 elements? @StevenGregory

Comment: Yes, because $\varphi(n) = |\mathbb U_n|$.

Comment: @mathamphetamines : The top row is $\langle 3 \rangle$ and the left column is $\langle 5 \rangle$. That makes the set of numbers displayed equal to $\langle 3, 5 \rangle$